# How to bindkey alt+key in OSX

Tags: macos, zsh, key-binding, alt

I am using oh-my-zsh configuration which has some handy bindkey condiguration. For example: "^[B" backward-word. On Linux I can use it with ease, but on OSX when I press alt-B i get some chars instead moving cursor. Can I configure somehow shortcuts alt+key on OSX or is there any trick to use them of of the box?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`M-b` and `M-f` should be bound to `backward-word` and `forward-word` by default:

```
$ zsh
$ bindkey | grep -- -word  
"^W" backward-kill-word
"^X*" expand-word
"^[^H" backward-kill-word
"^[^_" copy-prev-word
"^[\$" spell-word
"^[." insert-last-word
"^[B" backward-word
"^[C" capitalize-word
"^[D" kill-word
"^[F" forward-word
"^[L" down-case-word
"^[S" spell-word
"^[T" transpose-words
"^[U" up-case-word
"^[_" insert-last-word
"^[b" backward-word
"^[c" capitalize-word
"^[d" kill-word
"^[f" forward-word
"^[l" down-case-word
"^[s" spell-word
"^[t" transpose-words
"^[u" up-case-word
"^[^?" backward-kill-word
```

You just have to change the meta key:

[image]
[image]